# Styled Component function getting values from theme

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vzk8yx?file=index.tsx)

I have a simple react app using styled components

I have a simple styled Block that uses a function to generate the content

```
const widthFun = (a: number, b: number) => {
  return a + b;
};

const Block = styled.div`
  background: red;
  height: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height}px;
  width: ${widthFun(50, 50)}px;
`;
```

I also so have a theme like

```
import { DefaultTheme } from "styled-components";

export const theme: DefaultTheme = {
  sizes: {
    height: "200",
    width: "100"
  }
};
```

I'm trying to use the theme values in the function like

```
const Block = styled.div`
  background: red;
  height: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height}px;
  width: ${widthFun(50, 50)}px;
  width: ${widthFun(${({theme}) => theme.sizes.height}, ${({theme}) => theme.sizes.height})}px;
`;
```

I'm getting errors trying this.

Is it possible to use them values in a function in the styled-component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

how about this?

```
const Block = styled.div`
  background: red;
  height: ${({ theme }) => theme.sizes.height}px;
  width: ${widthFun(50, 50)}px;
  width: ${({ theme }) => widthFun(theme.sizes.height, theme.sizes.height)}px;
`;
```

Comment: This stops it erroring but doesn't set the width, the output now looks like `width: 100100px;`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qpuvje?file=index.tsx